# How to handle expressions in scipy.optimize.minimize?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, sympy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have a A vector which is a vector of expressions : A = [2*x - 2 2*y - 4 2*x + 2 2*y - 2]
I need to use A in the constraint of a minimization problem. My constraint is defined as :-

```
def constraint(x):
   alpha=x[0]
   v=x[1:len(x)]
   vnorm=calculateV(v)
   return A*v-alpha

cons={'type':'ineq','fun':constraint}
result=minimize(objective,val_start,constraints=cons,options={"disp":True})
```

However I get an error here citing :-

```
------Start--------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-13-7487d3726cc1>", line 49, in <module>
    result=minimize(objective,val_start,constraints=cons,options={"disp":True})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 618, in minimize
    constraints, callback=callback, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/slsqp.py", line 434, in _minimize_slsqp
    for con in cons['ineq']])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/slsqp.py", line 434, in <listcomp>
    for con in cons['ineq']])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/slsqp.py", line 277, in cjac
    return approx_jacobian(x, fun, epsilon, *args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/slsqp.py", line 63, in approx_jacobian
    jac[i] = (func(*((x0+dx,)+args)) - f0)/epsilon
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 350, in __float__
    raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")
TypeError: can't convert expression to float

------End--------
```

Comment: Your `expression` is a `sympy` object that does not have a `float` value.  Don't use `sympy` in `scipy/numpy`.  It doesn't work (most of the time).

Comment: @hpaulj - Actually A calculates the first order partial derivative of two equations. Thefore A will contain expressions. Do you have any idea ..how can I deal with such scenario? You may also suggest any other library which might fit the requirement.

Comment: In sympy you can use `lambdify` to convert a symbolic expression to a numpy-like function.  Your question is rather hard to answer without a complete, reproducible minimal example.